# Any magazine supplements for High Adventure Cliffhangers?

Tags: buck-rogers

Were there ever any published magazine articles or adventures in [*Dragon*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_%28magazine%29) or [*Dungeon*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeon_%28magazine%29) or other magazines for the [*High Adventure Cliffhangers*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_Rogers#High-Adventure_Cliffhangers) Buck Rogers RPG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buck Rogers: several were published in dragon 157. (I've got the CDRoms)

Dragon #157 has only introductory material, tho'; nothing playable.

All the other mentions I can find are one of (1) convention schedule, (2) reviews, (3) preview column blurbs, or (4)  adverts.

Dungeon never got the CD-Rom treatment, so I don't know.

Comment: It's too bad there wasn't more support. Thanks for looking.

Comment: No Problem. Was interesting to see how little they did with it. A number of adventures, but no real "visible" support in Dragon... which was the death knell for a TSR game.